# Lagrangian relaxation of optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, relaxations

> Use Lagrangian relaxation to solve the following optimization problem in $x, y\in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x^2 + 2 y^2\\ \text{subject to} & x + y \geq 2\\ & x^2 + y^2 \leq 5\end{array}$$

Solution :

Let $f(x,y)=x^2+2y^2$, $g_1(x,y)=2-x-y$, and $g_2(x,y)=x^2+y^2-5$.\~~
\
For $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}_+^2$ we define the Lagrangian Relaxation of the problem above :
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        min~&f_\lambda(x,y)\\
        subj.~to~~&x,y\in \mathbb{R}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
With,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
     f_\lambda(x,y)=&f(x,y)+\sum_{i=1}^2\lambda_ig_i(x,y)\\
     =&x^2+2y^2+\lambda_1(2-x-y)+\lambda_2(x^2+y^2-5)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

$f_\lambda$ is two times differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is open and convex. Moreover,
\begin{equation*}
    \nabla^2f_\lambda(x,y)=2
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1+\lambda_2&0\\
    0&2+\lambda_2
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Each eigenvalues of $\nabla^2f$ are positives therefore it is positive definite. So $f_\lambda$ is a convex function, thus a local min of $f_\lambda$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a global min.\
We want to find a local minimum by differentiating $f_\lambda$. If $\nabla f_\lambda(\bar x,\bar y)=0$ then $(\bar x,\bar y)$ is optimal for the Lagrangian relaxation of the problem.\
\begin{equation*}
    \nabla f_\lambda(\bar x,\bar y)=0~~\Leftrightarrow ~~
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2\bar x-\lambda_1+2\lambda_2\bar x\\
    4\bar y-\lambda_1+2\lambda_2\bar y\\
    \end{pmatrix} =0
    ~~\Leftrightarrow ~~
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \bar x \\
    \bar y
    \end{pmatrix}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
     \frac{\lambda_1}{2+2\lambda_2}\\
     \frac{\lambda_1}{4+2\lambda_2}
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Hence $(\bar x(\lambda) ,\bar y (\lambda))=( \frac{\lambda_1}{2+2\lambda_2}, \frac{\lambda_1}{4+2\lambda_2}) $ is optimal for the Lagrangian relaxation of the problem.\
Now, $(\bar x(\lambda) ,\bar y (\lambda))$ is optimal for the initial problem if :
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        &(i)~~g(\bar x(\lambda) ,\bar y (\lambda))\leq 0\\
        &(ii)~~\lambda_i g_i(\bar x(\lambda) ,\bar y (\lambda))=0,~~\text{for }i=1,2.\\
        &(iii)~~\lambda \geq 0
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

I choose $\lambda$ such that :
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
     &g_1(\bar x,\bar y)=0\\
    &g_1(\bar x,\bar y)=0 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
So, $(i),(ii)$ hold. my choice implies :
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        2-\frac{\lambda_1}{2(1+\lambda_2)}-\frac{\lambda_1}{2(2+\lambda_2)} &=0\\
        \frac{\lambda_1^2}{4(1+\lambda_2)^2}+\frac{\lambda_1^2}{4(2+\lambda_2)^2}-5 &=0\\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

$\Leftrightarrow$

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
       \lambda_1( \frac{1}{2(1+\lambda_2)}+\frac{1}{2(2+\lambda_2)}) &=2\\
        \lambda_1^2(\frac{1}{4(1+\lambda_2)^2}+\frac{1}{4(2+\lambda_2)^2}) &=5\\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

$\Leftrightarrow$
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
       \lambda_1^2(\frac{1}{4(1+\lambda_2)^2}+\frac{1}{4(2+\lambda_2)^2}+\frac{1}{2(1+\lambda_2)(2+\lambda_2)}) &=4\\
        \lambda_1^2(\frac{1}{4(1+\lambda_2)^2}+\frac{1}{4(2+\lambda_2)^2}) &=5\\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

$\Leftrightarrow$
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
       \lambda_1^2(\frac{1}{2(1+\lambda_2)(2+\lambda_2)}) &=-1\\
        \lambda_1^2(\frac{1}{4(1+\lambda_2)^2}+\frac{1}{4(2+\lambda_2)^2}) &=5\\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

$\Leftrightarrow$
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
       \lambda_1^2&=-2(1+\lambda_2)(2+\lambda_2)\\
        \lambda_1^2(\frac{1}{4(1+\lambda_2)^2}+\frac{1}{4(2+\lambda_2)^2}) &=5\\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

So I get :
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        -2(1+\lambda_2)(2+\lambda_2)(\frac{1}{4(1+\lambda_2)^2}+\frac{1}{4(2+\lambda_2)^2}) &=5\\
        \Leftrightarrow~~~\frac{(2+\lambda_2)^2+(1+\lambda_2)^2}{2(1+\lambda_2)(2+\lambda_2)}&=-5\\
          \Leftrightarrow~~~ 12 \lambda_2^2+36 \lambda_2+25&=0\\
           \Leftrightarrow~~~ \lambda_2&=\frac{-36\pm \sqrt{96}}{24}\leq 0
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Therefore $(iii)$ is not verified.
$$ $$
And if I choose $\lambda =0$ then $(i)$ is not verified.
$$ $$
I'm stuck here...

Comment: You found the minimum of the Lagrangian function once $\lambda$ is fixed, which is a first step. 
Now you need to find the maximum of the Lagrangian dual function to find a saddle-point.

Comment: Thank you I found the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Show that $$x^2+2y^2\geq \frac{8}{3}$$ the equal sign holds if $$x=\frac{4}{3}y=\frac{2}{3}$$, Since $$f(x,y)=x^2+2y^2$$ we get
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=2x$$ and $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=4y$$ you should search the extreme points on the curves $x+y=2$ and $$x^2+y^2=5$$

Comment: Ok thank you but your method don't use Lagrangian relaxation... And for my assignement I have to use it.